# The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using Word press that Hosted on Blue Host

after activate Jetpack and when click on "connect to wordpress.com" button, i see this error:

site_inaccessible

The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site [HTTP 404]. Ask your web host if they allow connections from WordPress.com. If you need further assistance, contact Jetpack Support: http://jetpack.me/support/

Comment: can u check, in the wp_options table for "site_url" and 'home' values

Comment: and confirm that `xmlrpc.php` file is exist in ur root folder, this  file will need to be available, and publicly accessible, in order for Jetpack to connect to WordPress.com

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because I have installed [iThemes Security plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/). To solve the problem :

1. Disable it.
2. Connect JetPack
3. Enable it and look what exactly in the config is making the problem.

   Probably other security plug-ins/firewalls will have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

The jetpack plugin error in wordpress is due to the ModSecurity is enabled in the cpanel and  xmrpc rule is not added in the .htaccess file.

First diable the mod securty for the domain from cpanel.

1. Log into cPanel
2. Under Security choose ModSecurity
3. Under Configure Individual Domains, Switch affected On or Off (For all domains, ModSecurity is On by default)

Add xmlrpc.php requests rule in .htaccess

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

And check xmlrpc is working or not 
http://example.com/xmlrpc.php

Answer (score 1):

i deactivating all plugins and uninstall jetpack , after reinstall jetpack its work successfuly. thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a security plugin or your host may be blocking access to this file. As long as this is the case, you won't be able to use Jetpack, or any other app or plugin using the XML-RPC file.

### yourblog/wordpress/xmlrpc.php

Could you try to deactivate all security plugins, and if that doesn't help to contact your hosting provider and ask them if they block access top the URL above?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: This worked for me. I had a security plugin WP Cerber disabling XML-RPC. I enabled it and Jetpack worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all types of work around and none has solved, even this above. At least with me.

What I found was, comparing with other running websites I have this one, which is a new installation had a strange folder within the same folder installation.

A folder called ".didb", I never heard of it and there was several text files within. Searched online to see if was something important to have on server, nothing clear found.

So guess what I did. Deleted the sweet folder and boom. Is working perfectly well now.

Sorry, I don't have the names of the files and folders within, and to be honest, I don't want to know, all I want to know if is the website is working with the files I want which is WordPress only.

So, you may have a similar situation, take a look under your high level folder via FTP or whichever other way you may want to and that could save the day. ;-)